# Why doesn't my remote-controlled ceiling fan turn on?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I just installed a new ceiling fan. When I turn on the switch on the wall, the light on the fan turns on. But when I try to turn on the fan (which needs to be done with the remote), I just hear a click from the fan, but the blades don't spin.

After my wiring at the switch wasn't working, I tried twisting all 3 black wires together, and all three white ones together. Even then, the fan does not turn on.

This is a brand new fan, so I feel sure I'm doing something wrong. Just not sure what. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What make and model is said fan? Does it start spinning if you give the blades a push while it's turned on? (think of hand-propping a plane)

Answer (score 0):

If you're hearing a click one time, then that sounds like the relay that is supposed to connect power to the fan motor. Usually relays either work or don't work. It would be strange to hear the click of a relay (a sign it is working) but not see the electrical load turn on (a sign that it is bad).

It's worth making sure nothing is obstructing the motor or blades from spinning. If they are blocked, then it would make sense to hear the click of the relay but see no motion.

If there is internal wiring you can access for the fan after the relay, then you could put a multimeter on those wires (A/C 115 volts). And then hit the remote button on/off to verify power is getting to those wires. If it is, then suspect the fan motor. If it isn't then suspect the fan relay/remote control receiver.

Not really an answer but I hope that helps.